# Excluding iPhone3GS and down from downloading my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, constraints

How can I exclude iPhone 3GS users and below from downloading my app? I know this has been asked, but the app store changes rapidly, so I want to make sure I am doing it the right way. Is there any place to select what to exclude in the build settings? Or do I have to set UIRequirements?

PS: The reason I want to exclude them is because my GUIElements would be out of place.

Comment: Why would your GUI elements be out of place? If you created them correctly they should be fine. Have you tested them in the simulator for non retina displays?

Comment: I used unity3d, and set up my gui for retina displays. If I support non-retina displays, my gui elements will be oversized and slighty out of place. I plan to open up to non-retina in updates, but I want my app out before the rush of valentine's day apps kill it.

Comment: What happens if you run the app on an ipad? The scaled apps use non retina graphics. If it fails on the iPad it won't go into the app store. In this case you should probably add telephony to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities too.

Comment: but then iPod Touch users wouldn't be able to download my app!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the property `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, you set this options in the properties list (plist) file found in your Xcode project. If you want to exclude iPhone 3GS and lower you could test for a front-facing camera.

Good luck!

[Source.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

Comment: Would the apple review team be ok with it?

Comment: The Apple review team should not have a problem with that. This is an open API and if you think some devices shouldn't be able to run your app then they shouldn't run it. Good luck!

Comment: However, you can not use this method to exclude 3GS in a new version of your App, i.e. if you released version 1.0.0 supporting 3GS then all further versions must have the same restrictions in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. Requiring iOS 7.0 should be soon a best solution.

Comment: @ElDeveloper If my app is Universal, then this methoed also disabling a iPad1, how i can disable Only a iPhone3GS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` and require the app has a front-facing-camera

Comment: Would the appstore review team be okay with this?

Comment: Depends. Its kind of a grey area.

Comment: Do you think it would go through? Have you ever tried or know about someone who did this and got accepted to the app store?

Comment: Lots of people have had their apps accepted with this hack. A smaller percentage have been rejected for it.

Comment: @MobileOverlord If my app is Universal, then this methoed also disabling a iPad1, how i can disable Only a iPhone3GS ?