# Excluding iPhone 3GS and older iPhones and iPods from universal App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app, iphone-3gs

I want to achieve the same as the guy in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146625/excluding-iphone3gs-and-down-from-downloading-my-app) but using a universal App. That is, including all the iPad versions and all the iPhones and iPods that have retina display.

I think that the keys I need to add to my info.plist file in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities section are:

- armv7
- front-facing-camera~iphone
- front-facing-camera~ipod

What I'm not sure of is if the ~iphone and ~ipod suffixes are enough to let the system know that I want to include the iPad 1 (which does not have a front Camera)

Can anyone confirm that this is the correct way to do this?

The guys at the apple support portal would only point me to the docs and guides, but I haven't found any real example of what I want to do.

Comment: Did they direct you to any part of the documentation specifically?

Comment: Yup: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW6)
There's an example using the ~ipad suffix after a valid key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "suffix". This keys allows you to list ’hardware-like’ capabilities that your app needs. 
So.. let's say: microphone - your app "need" microphone! You can't say "I need microphone.. if is iPad"...

Comment: It seems you're right. Do you know any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW6) explains how to use the suffix, but it may work for some keys only.

Comment: Having the App already available for iPad, is it OK to assume that if I use the front-facing-camera key for the next version it will restrict only the older iPhones and iPods but will keep allowing the iPad 1?

Comment: NO; iPad1 will be excluded ... Sorry no suffix for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Cannot Be Changed in App Updates "Developers can add restrictions to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities on app updates provided any device that is dropped cannot support the min os version specified." http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/

Comment: You can add just armv7.. and detect the device type ([UIDevice currentDevice]). For iPod G2, G3 .. or whatever.. you can add some "alerts": "due to hardware requirements - on your device you can encounter some minor flaws... "

Comment: It appears that you were right. I couldn't use those keys (with or without suffix) so I checked the device and popped an alert if the device was not supported. I'll close this question once the app has been approved or rejected, adding more detail if I get to know more about this. Thanks

Comment: OK. My App has been approved!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this would work - especially if there is a key for `front-facing-camera~ipad`.

Comment: I'm sure that front-facing-camera have a key, but it's the first time I use a device specific suffix. I don't want to make a mistake and enable devices that I won't be able to restrict later, nor disabling a device such as the iPad 1.

Comment: @emibap Do you have an original iPad to test on?

Comment: Just tested the keys using many devices and it's not working as expected. Builds OK but can´t copy to device (No such file or directory...). And if I use the key without suffix It doesn't work on the iPad 1 :(